# React native(root is missing ) while running application

Tags: react-native

After creating react native app when i used to run this using react-native run-android that time i am getting error as root missing

> error Option "--root" is missing. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more
> details. Error: Option "--root" is missing
> at C:\Users\Mayuri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\assertRequiredOptions.js:51:13

[image]

Comment: follow this link it might help you

[link](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/5282#issuecomment-534715667)

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue. My guess is it has something to do with the react-native-cli(maybe not being uptodate). Try reinstalling like this: npm uninstall -g react-native-cli, npm install -g react-native-cli. Also, Dont forget to add the location of the Android SDK to the project. This worked for me.

Comment: just add npx before that ..it will run automatically ..This worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using the latest version of react-native 64 and npm greater than 5.2 you need to execute your packages using npx command so rather than running

```
react-native run-android
```

run

```
npx react-native run-android
```

Comment: Actually, instead of running `npx react-native run-android`, while running `react-native run-android` worked for me.